# SFMC automation - Archiving only new records from source data extension into an archive data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I want to create an automation which when scans for new records that were inserted into a Data Extension and then copies those records to another Data Extension (archive). The source DE has a retention policy in place so records get deleted after some time, hence the need for creating an archive Data Extension with stores all historical records.

In short, I'm looking for a query which looks at source data extensions and gets me records that don't exist in the archive Data Extension.

Please note **none** of the fields in the source Data Extension have a Primary Key so joining 2 Data Extensions takes time to run. It's a relatively large table of approx. 15 million records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that came to my mind how you can do it (of course there could be more):

1. Add a new "Date" data type field in the Source DE with default value = "Current Date". This way, that new field will have a timestamp once a new record is added to the Source DE. Then add SQL Query Activity with the "Update" method to the Automation and archive all records added from the last day. The automation would be running every day as well. Here is an example of the query:

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey
FROM [Source_DE]
WHERE
Date >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()-1) AND Date < CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

2. You can use Exclusion Left Join if you would be able to set a proper relationship between Source and Archive DEs. So that, you would be pick values from Source DE that are not found in the Archive and then use the "Append" method to Archive DE. This is not recommended method considering the absence of PKs and 15 mils of records, yet it still also depends on the number of fields you have and thus you can give it a try. The query would like this:

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey
FROM [Source_DE] a
LEFT JOIN [Archive_DE] b
ON a.Field = b.Field
WHERE b.Field IS NULL
```

Comment: I've basically used Option 2 to achieve the desired outcome.